# Why the distance of any point on a ellipse is equal to an equation of a line?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I don't see the geometric reason of the following equation $$\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2}=a-\frac{c}{a}x$$ Why the distance of any point $$P(x,y)$$ on a ellipse is equal to an equation of a line?
Thank you.

Comment: All conic sections can be characterized as the set of points a certain distance away from a point and a line. If they are equidistant you have a parabola. If they are closer to the point than the line, an ellipse, and vice versa gives a hyperbola. Assuming, of course, the distances were at a fixed ratio.

Comment: The line $a - \frac ca x = 0$ (it's not an equation until there's an $=$ sign in it!) is a directrix of the ellipse. You can look it up [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse.html).

Comment: The distance of any point from where? Something wrong with question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A conics is  defined as collection or locus of points $P(x,y)$ which move such that there distance from a fixed point $S(ae,0)$ always equals $e$ times, its perpendicular distance from a fixed line $x=a/e.$ This gives a connection/equation of $x,y$ which represents ellipse if $e<1$, hyperbola is $e>1$ and parabola if $e=1$.
$$\sqrt{(x-ae)^2+y^2}=(x-a/e) \implies \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{a^2(1-e^2)}=1$$
An equation of a curve is a relationship between $x,y$ which cannot be dissected as line or some thing. For example $x^2+y^2=2x+2y-1$ is equation of circle even if RHS appears to be  an equation of a line. Do not dissect and equation like you have thought.

Comment: I would add the name "focus" for point $S$ and "directrix" for the "fixed line".

Comment: Yes, you are rifght.